# ASP.NET Check if LoginName is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application on VS2005 C# and I would want to check if user is logged in the application.

Currently I am trying

```
if (LoginName.Equals(null))
{
    Response.Redirect("/Project/Login.aspx");
}
```

but I seem to be getting some errors.

Anyone can tell me how I should do it or is there any better ways too check?

Thank you

---

EDIT:

Sorry for being unclear with my question.

`LoginName` is the *System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName*.

The error I am getting is `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field , method or property 'object.Equals(object)'

Comment: What errors? Be specific, if you need the community to help!

Comment: Show the definition of `LoginName` and how it is instantiated.

Comment: Did you try `string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginName)` ?

Comment: What type is `LoginName`? Is it a string containing the name, a control in which the user has entered the name, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual question seems to be *How can i check if a user is authenticated*? You should edit the title of your question.

When using an ASP.NET authenticationprovider you can check if a user is authenticated with this code in your code behind files:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

You can access the username for example with

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

If LoginName variable is a string you can use this

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginName))
 {
 .....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just think about what you wrote:

```
if (LoginName.Equals(null))
```

This statement may end up in two different ways:

1. It may return `false` (`LoginName` does not equal `null`)
2. An exception is thrown. Why? If `LoginName` does equal `null`, you're calling a method on an instance variable that is not set to an instance of an object (=> is set to  `null`) and thus you're getting a `NullReferenceException`.

So what can you do?

Instead of performing a `null` check using `Equals` (which doesn't make sense at all, as shown above), you could either do:

```
if (LoginName == null)
```

or you could do

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginName))
```

This would be even better.

Comment: both methods gave me the error : *Error 52 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'*

Comment: Aha! Then you need to get access to an *instance* of the `LoginName` class. I thought `LoginName` was a string variable in your project, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

```
if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
Response.Redirect("\Projects\Login.aspx");
```

can be used or you can also use session Variables